# convert ordered dictionary to pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have been trying to convert the ordered dictionary columns to pandas dataframe columns. 
my Dataframe is as follows:

```
a    b    c
1    2    OrderedDict([('@value','N'),('dsc','false')])
3    4    0
```

This is my sample dataframe with a,b,c columns. The only problem i face is my col c has some ordered dict and some 0 values. I tried pd.series or .tolist() for this problem and the job abends.

anyone please help me for this.

Comment: How are you generating this dataframe in the first place, which gives you `OrderedDict` columns?

Comment: i have converted xml tags to dataframe using json.normalize and since the xml tags have many nested tags. it ended in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the OrderedDict into a list as:

```
l = list(OrderedDict([('@value','N'),('dsc','false')]).items())
```

Output:

```
[('@value', 'N'), ('dsc', 'false')]
```

Now you can convert it into pandas columns.

Hope it helps. Please let me know.